# some variables in xml have a 'dot'

Tags: android, xml, reference

I am now studying a opensource android mobile browser, notice some variables in xml have a 'dot' to define a long name variable.
such as:

```
TextView android:id="@+id/BookmarksListActivity.EmptyTextView"
```

and i notice the reference in `*.java is *BookmarksListActivity_EmptyTextView*`

is it a correct way to use the variables like that?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the same in my project and it works. I don't know why one would need that but that works.

Comment: I get used to search a specific variable using "CTRL + H", if i try to search "BookmarksListActivity_EmptyTextView", I get no result.
it seems not convenient to find such variable in a big project.